# How to exclude certain SKU to be calculated in Minimum Order Amount

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, shopping-cart-price-rules, customization

I'm currently using the native M2 Minimum Order Amount module.

I want to add to my store some products, but I don't want them to be consider during minimum order amount calculation.

Minimum_Order_Amount = 30

Example
If cart contains some SKU's
Then Minimum_Order_Amount += itemRowSubtotal

I'm wondering how to approach this problem?
Also I would like to return dynamic error equivalent to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize Minimum Order Amount module. First find where are this products getting added to the minmimun_order_amount. Next thing create a product attribute which will hold some Yes/No value to indicate Weather to use for minimum order amount or not.
Now going back to first point where you founded the amount being added to minimum_order_amount. Put an if condition base on the product